# Looking for examples of the record library for SWI-prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, record

I am looking for example uses (or tutorials) of the record library

http://www.cs.fit.edu/~pkc/classes/ai/swi-prolog/Manual/record.html

for SWI-prolog that I can use as a template.  Do you have any pointers?

Thanks,

SetJmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one example of usage here in the SWI-Prolog JSON library to hold JSON options
http://www.swi-prolog.org/git/packages/http.git/blob/HEAD:/json.pl

It is pretty straightforward to use.  the only pain is that you can't pull arbitrary fields off a record because they need to be accessed by _(X). Also, i do not believe any extra meta-data about the record is stored in case you want to get the field names at run time.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "accessed by _(X)" statement?  I am parsing JSON and get back something like

PRLG_Out = reading_datum(1, datum(2, 3.3))

when executing json_to_prolog(JSON_In,PRLG_Out).  How does one get the individual fields of this "reading_datum" thingy?